# Update with php form letter fails, with numbers to succeed

Tags: php, html, mysql

Made new column in MySQL base,  `varchar(150)` `utf8_general_ci`   And made webform to enter data easily. When I use numbers then form works, but when I use any letter then gives an error : `Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in`

form  something like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


     $liige_id = $_POST['liige_id'];
        $wplink = $_POST['wplink'];

    $sql = "UPDATE liige_v ".
           "SET wplink = $wplink ".
           "WHERE liige_id = $liige_id" ;

    $retval = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );

    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
     }
    echo "Sisestasid edukalt selle liikme info\n";
    mysqli_close($con);
    }
    else
    {
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="5">Liikme ID</td>
<td><input name="liige_id" type="text" id="liige_id"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="75">WordPress link </td>
<td><input name="wplink" type="text" id="wplink"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Uuenda"
```

Comment: Enclose you MySql query values in single-quotes. ie: `wplink = '$wplink'`

Comment: Thank's @PedroLobito single-quotes is the key ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quote the variable.

Integers do not need to be quoted, non-integer values need to be quoted.

```
$sql = "UPDATE liige_v ".
           "SET wplink = '$wplink' ".
           "WHERE liige_id = '$liige_id' " ;
```

When a submitted variable is always numeric use intval() to make it zero if empty or non-numeric.

```
$number = intval($_POST['number']);
```

This will prevent SQL errors and qualifies that the value is numeric.

Comment: Thank's @Misunderstood Single quote is helping me ;)